# Google Kickstart 2020 Round C: Countdown - Code Not Working

Tags: java

When I submit my code on Google Kickstart, I get a "wrong answer" for the 1st test set, even though the sample input and output match. I'm really not sure why Google does not accept the code.

[The task](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff43/00000000003380d2) is that given an array of **N** positive integers, find the number of **K**-countdowns, where a **K**-countdown is a contiguous subarray if it is of length **K** and contains the integers K, K-1, K-2, ..., 2, 1 in that order.

Input:

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the integers N and K. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai.

Output:

For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number of K-countdowns in her array.

Sample Input:

```
3
12 3
1 2 3 7 9 3 2 1 8 3 2 1
4 2
101 100 99 98
9 6
100 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 100
```

Sample Output:

```
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 0
Case #3: 1
```

My logic is pretty straightforward: I have a counter variable **x** which starts at **K** and decrements whenever an integer equals **x**. If a countdown is found (**x**=0 after decrementing) then the answer increases and **x** is set to equal **K**. Here is the crux of my code:

```
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        arr[i]=sc.nextLong();
        if(arr[i]==x)
            x--;
        else 
            x=k;
        if(x==0) {
            ans++;
            x=k;
        }
    }
```

Here is my entire code in case there are any trivial errors:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {
    static int t;
    static long n,k;
    static long[] arr;
    static Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        t=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=t; i++) {
            n=sc.nextLong();
            k=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println("Case #"+i+": "+solve());
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    public static long solve() {
        long x=k;
        long ans=0;
        arr=new long[(int)n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            arr[i]=sc.nextLong();
            if(arr[i]==x)
                x--;
            else 
                x=k;
            if(x==0) {
                ans++;
                x=k;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there is half of a countdown in the array and the following number is **K**. 
Based on the code, that number will be neglected and so if there is a following countdown, it won't be counted. Here is what the main loop should look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextLong();

    if (arr[i] == x)
        x--;
    else if (arr[i] == k)
        x = k-1;
    else 
        x = k;

    if (x == 0) {
        ans++;
        x = k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my cpp code which is running in o(n)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int t,m;
cin>>t;
m=t;
while(t--){
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    vector <int> v,v2;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int tr;
        cin>>tr;
        v.push_back(tr);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
        int tr=k-j;
        v2.push_back(tr);
    }
    int fg=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(v[i]==k){
                int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
                if(v2[j]==v[i+j])
                    count++;
            }
        if(count==k)
            fg++;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Case #"<<m-t<<": "<<fg<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a useful answer, especially considering that this is a java-related question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Accepted code in java :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static int kCountDown(int [] nums, int k) {
        int length = nums.length;
        int endCounter = 0;
        int result = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<length; i++) {
            if (nums[i - 1] - nums[i] == 1)
                endCounter += 1;
            else
                endCounter = 0;
            if (nums[i] == 1 && endCounter >= k - 1)
                result += 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = sc.nextInt();
        for (int t=1; t<=test; t++) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int k = sc.nextInt();
            int [] nums = new int [n];
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Case #" + t + ": " + kCountDown(nums, k));
        }
    }
}
```

Complexity is O(n) where n = length of the input array